# How to Retrieve a record in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am start learning MVC3, I got an error when I am trying to develop an Employee table application.

When user click on the detail link, How to retrieve it from database?

Please have a look for the code of the below image

```
    public ActionResult Details(int ID)
    {
        tblEmployee tblEmp = test.tblEmployees.Find(ID);
        return View(tblEmp);
    }
```

Error is as follows:

> Error 3   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension method
>   'Find' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method as `Find()` in the `ObjectSet<>` class. You might want to use this one: [`DbSet<>.Find()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). Either change the type of `tblEmployees` to `DbSet<tblEmployee>` or use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `Find()`:

```
tblEmployee tblEmp = test.tblEmployees.FirstOrDefault(employee => employee.ID == ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
public ActionResult Details(int ID)
{
    tblEmployee tblEmp = test.tblEmployees.Single(x=> x.ID  == ID);
    return View(tblEmployee);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply  I tried your code and  got an error as follows                                                       Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: Your constraint is wrong - `.Single(x=> x.ID)` should be `.Single(x=> x.ID == ID)`